# Sending Email Template FROM: Different Addresses By Same User

Tags: email, email-template, administration, appexchange, business-logic

Does anyone know of a solution for **User "Anthony" being able to PICK from more than ONE EMAIL ADDRESS to be the "FROM:" address when sending a Template** (without using an open text box when sending the email?

This is a new requirement, as we have **employees who do work for MORE THAN ONE DIVISION of our company**, and they have email addresses in each Division.

**Org-wide emails** don't seem feasible - you'd have to create all the email addresses and then magically limit specific ones to specific people (we don't want "John at OrgONE" to email FROM: "Peter at OrgTWO").

Without actually giving them multiple SF User records (license cost, maintenance, etc),  I consider the possibility of Email custom fields on their User record for each Division, but am afraid this will require Visualforce or Apex to then actually USE them.

---

**Desired:**

- User & Primary Email:    amalena@orgONE.com
- Division 2 Email:    amalena@orgTWO.com
- Division 3 Email:    anthonym@theOtherORG.com

When preparing to send an email template, ideally a PICKLIST of these email addresses to populate the FROM: field.

---

Alternative ideas that accomplish this are welcome, or even a Plugin from AppExchange.

Comment: Side note:   The only alternative that sounds REMOTELY possible or at least "less problematic" would be Org-Wide Emails that are GENERIC ("Sales@orgONE.com", "Sales@OrgTWO.com", etc).   Not great, but maybe I'm missing how this could be the solution???

Comment: We are doing something similar in our org and we have a validation rule on Email Message and it prevents user from selecting a from address that they are not supposed to use. Ideal solution would be to display the from addresses that they can use but I think that is not possible.

Comment: (thanks for the one who corrected a couple typos on this)   ;)

Comment: Even the thought of VALIDATION on an outgoing email is something new to me;  I never would have imagined such a thing existed as I've never had this need before.    That at least could be part of a solution, not the best solution, if they're typing their own "FROM" address each time, but at least (since I know their Division(s), I could lock them down to valid DOMAINS when sending).   Hmm...

Comment: The more I think about this... the more I wonder if a custom button could do it.    That may STILL be prolematic since Rootstock (where many templates need to be sent from within SF) is Managed, and I cannot put buttons anywhere.    Theoretically, a button, tied to a template, could be hardcoded to use "their Alternate Email 2" custom field on their user.........

Comment: I am not sure if we can override Send Email Message page. Just to make sure we are talking about the same thing, I am referring to the page that shows up once you click on the 'Send Email' button on the case related list or other detail pages.

Comment: Ignore my above comment. I think it is possible override Send Email Message page with a custom VF page but not sure if it is worth the effort. Please post the code if you are able to override so that we could reuse in our org! :)

Comment: Sounds "logical".   Biggest issue on my end is, as I investigate further, I'm really pidgeonholed into the MANAGED PACKAGE situation (Rootstock).     Ugh.   Will post more as I learn.